# Can I use third party java libraries(.jar) for Android development with Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I haven't moved to Kotlin for Android development yet, just wondering if Kotlin supports the available third party libraries for Android as is or they need to be updated in order to work with Kotlin?

Comment: You can use any existing Java library with Kotlin, same as you would with Java.

Comment: No need to downvote, this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course you can do that, see the examples :

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**, as **Kotlin is 100% interoperable with Java**, and both works on JVM. so one can easily use Java libraries with Kotlin.

Please refer [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/android-overview.html).

Answer (score 2):

yes, Kotlin is fully interoperable with Java